# How to use regex to modify a string in pandas in different cases

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, replace

I have the following dataframe called df:

```
   Symbol  Country  Type  etc...
0  AG.L    UK       OS
1  UZ.     UK       OS
2  DT      UK       OS
3  XX.L    US       OS
4  MSFT    US       OS
5  AAPL    US       OS
6  DB.S    SG       OS
```

I want to perform the following on the frame. Where the Country == 'UK',

there can be 3 cases.

`Case 1: ends with .L,
do nothing
Case 2: ends with .,
add 'L' to the end
Case3: ends with neither . or .L,
add '.L' to the end`

As long as the Country == 'UK', I want it to end with a '.L'.

So it should look like this.

```
   Symbol  Country  Type  etc...
0  AG.L    UK       OS
1  UZ.L    UK       OS
2  DT.L    UK       OS
3  XX.L    US       OS
4  MSFT    US       OS
5  AAPL    US       OS
6  DB.S    SG       OS
```

I use the following code.

```
df.loc[df['Country'].eq('UK'),'Symbol'] = df.loc[df['Country'].eq('UK'),'Symbol'].str.replace(r'\.', '.L').str.replace(r'[a-z]$', '.L')
```

but i get this

```
AG.LL  
UZ.L    
DT
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Is it possible to replace '([^L])$' by $1L in python? So add an L to the last character if it is not an L. Don't know the exact syntax for capture groups and backreferences in python. You have to find out for yourself.

Comment: DB.S wont be affected because its not in UK

Comment: sorry, my edit made your comment outdated. You are right about DB.S not in UK, but it is a bug in the replace. If you replace ALL periods by .L, that will have an effect for UK symbols with a period in the middle . THat is the reason for AG.LL: the period is replaced by .L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right, but you missed the dollar sign at the dot replacement and the other one has to be slightly different, so try:

```
df.loc[df['Country'].eq('UK'),'Symbol'] =  df.loc[df['Country'].eq('UK'),'Symbol'].str.replace(r'^([A-Z]+)$', r'\1.L').str.replace(r'\.$', '.L')
```

In my Python shell it outputs:

```
0    AG.L
1    UZ.L
2    DT.L
Name: Symbol, dtype: object
```